# JS Getting an unwantend 'enter/return' when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, forms, input, enter

Im using `$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) { if (e.which === 13) {` to get to the next input field. But everytime i press **enter/return** to go to the next input field, it starts in the input field with an extra **enter/return** (or `<br />`).

How can i disable it?

**The solution (thanks to epascarello):**  `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Please show the whole code. How are you going to the next input field? It might be better to use `keyup` rather than `keydown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you do not want it than cancel it with preventDefault

```
$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //put focus code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick! stupid of me of forgetting  `e.preventDefault();`